# How to get mapped values from string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string like,

```
const string =
    "DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048','060','070') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('1','3') AND NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR IN ('S') AND NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT IN ('H','C')";
```

From this, I need to map the respective key and value like, `DEVICE_SIZE: ["036", "048", "060", "070"]`

**Current Result:**

```js
  const string =
    "DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048','060','070') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('1','3') AND NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR IN ('S') AND NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT IN ('H','C')";

  const res = string.split('IN ');

  const regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;

  const Y = 'AND';

  const data = res.map((item) => {
    if (regExp.exec(item)) {
      return {
        [item.slice(item.indexOf(Y) + Y.length)]: regExp.exec(item)[1],
      };
    }
  });

  console.log('data ', data);
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[
  { "DEVICE_SIZE": ["036", "048", "060", "070"] },
  { "DEVICE_VOLTAGE": ["1", "3"] },
  { "NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR": ["s"] },
  { "NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT": ["H", "C"] },
];
```

I couldn't get the exact result based on my try in the current result. Could you please kindly help me to achieve the above given expected result?

**Note**: I am trying the above to achieve the end result mentioned in my previous question
[How to get valid object from the string matching respective array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74580671/how-to-get-valid-object-from-the-string-matching-respective-array)

Comment: Parsing string like that is prone to errors and will most likely break, why you need to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of a single regex with 2 capture groups to match the key and the value.

```
((?:\bNOT\s+)?\w+)\s+IN\s+\('([^()]*)'\)
```

See the [regex  demo](https://regex101.com/r/aovs6J/1).

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:\bNOT\s+)?` Optionally match the word NOT followed by 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\w+` Match 1 or more word characters
- `)` Close group
- `\s+IN\s+` Match the word IN between whitespace characters
- `\('` Match `('`
- `([^()]*)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ occurrences of any char except `(` and `)`
- `'\)` Match `')`

To create the dynamic keys for the object, you can make use of [Object Initializer](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) and you can split on `','` to create the resulting array for the value.

```js
const regex = /((?:\bNOT\s+)?\w+)\s+IN\s+\('([^()]*)'\)/g;
const string = "DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048','060','070') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('1','3') AND NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR IN ('S') AND NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT IN ('H','C')";
const data = Array.from(
  string.matchAll(regex), m =>
  ({
    [m[1]]: m[2].split("','")
  })
);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have split by `AND` first and then split again with `IN` to separate the key and the value part.

This would also work:

```js
const string =
  "DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048','060','070') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('1','3') AND NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR IN ('S') AND NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT IN ('H','C')";

const output = string
  .split("AND")
  .map((item) => item.split("IN").map((text) => text.trim()))
  .map(([key, value]) => ({
    [key]: value.replace(/[\(\)\']/g, "").split(","),
  }));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.fromEntries`, which transforms key-value tuples `[string, any]` into an object with those tuples:

```js
const data = Object.fromEntries(res.map((item) => {
    if (regExp.exec(item)) {
      return [item.slice(item.indexOf(Y) + Y.length).trim(), regExp.exec(item)[1].split(',').map(value => value.slice(1, -1))];
    }
    return undefined;
}).filter(Boolean));
```

and then continue from there.